# Create fixed width and length polygon buffer from endpoints of polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

Is there a way to generate a polygonal buffer on the end of an existing polygon in QGIS? The red polygon was added using MS Paint as an example of what I would like to achieve. Ideally, the red polygon would extend from the orange polygon from the center point (red vertex) - equally or similar to a buffer. It would be even better if the red polygon could maintain the width of the orange polygon. Not sure if this is possible or something Geometry by Expression could handle.

[image: polygon_buffer_on_end_of_polygon]

Comment: What is the "end of a polygon"? You have only rectangles and you want to create the buffer at the smaller side of it? At both ends or just one end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QGIS expressions with [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) and this expression for rectangles - see screenshot at the bottom.

Variants:

- If you want the "buffers" only on one side, in line 3 replace `(-1,1)` by `(1)` to get only one end or by `(-1)` to get only the other end.
- In case you want the "buffers" on the long side of the rectangle, in line 18 change `radians (main_angle ($geometry))` into `radians (main_angle( $geometry)-90)`

```
collect_geometries (
    array_foreach(
        array(-1,1),  --change here to get buffers only at one end
        with_variable (
            'int',
            intersection (
                boundary($geometry),
                make_line(
                    centroid ($geometry),
                    project (
                        centroid($geometry),
                        @element* length (
                            make_line(
                                centroid($geometry),
                                point_n($geometry,1)
                            )
                        ),
                        radians (main_angle ($geometry))  -- change here to get buffers at the long side of rectangles
                    )
                )
            ),
            make_regular_polygon(
                @int, 
                project (
                    @int, 
                    length(
                        make_line (
                            @int,
                            closest_point (
                                nodes_to_points($geometry),
                                @int
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    radians (main_angle ($geometry))
                ),
                4,
                1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

*Yellow: original rectangles, blue with red outline: created "buffers":*
[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer to my question. What would I change in your expression if I wanted to save the results to a shapefile using Geometry by Expression?

Comment: Should work the same for `Geometry by expression`

Comment: I'm getting ---> Evaluation error: Cannot convert to geometry

Comment: For me, it works - testet right now. When you use geometry generator, does it work?

Comment: Yes - your solution works using the Geometry Generator, but returns the evaluation error listed above.

Comment: Can you share your data?

Comment: Sure - I'm new to posting so is there a place I could send the file or do I share all of the information in this thread?

Comment: Upload it to a cloud and share the link here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xqiylgxxz385iwp/AAAxW_sRfGdG21iHaOUr7zMca?dl=0

Comment: Your layer is in a geographic CRS, that does not work well with distances. Reproject to a projected CRS, then it will work.

Comment: The reprojection worked - thanks!